# passing a parameter from html page url mapping to the views in django

Tags: python, django, url-mapping

**front.html**

```
<div class="row">
   <a href="{% url 'emp_pay_list' Information_technology %}">
      <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
        <div class="dash-widget clearfix card-box" style="height: 200px;">
            <span class="dash-widget-icon"><i class="fa fa-cubes" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
            <div class="dash-widget-info">
                <h3>20</h3>
                <span>Information Technology</span>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
   </a>

   <a href="{% url 'emp_pay_list' sales %}">
       <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
          <div class="dash-widget clearfix card-box" style="height: 200px;">
              <span class="dash-widget-icon"><i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
              <div class="dash-widget-info">
                 <h3>7</h3>
                  <span>Sales Team</span>
              </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

The above code is the front end part HTML here I want to pass a parameter into the urls.py by clicking a box and depends on the parameter which we pass the data should be fetched.

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^list_of_employees/<string>/$', views.Pay_slip_list , name='emp_pay_list'),
```

This is the code which I am using in urls.py to pass parameter.

views.py

```
def Pay_slip_list(request, department):
    hello = employees.objects.select_related('employee_name', 'employee_auth').filter(department=department)
    return render(request, 'hr/emp_pay_list.html', {'hello': hello})
```

And this is the views.py part where I am fetching data from the database based on the string/parameter passed after clicking the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URL pattern must look like

```
from django.urls import path, re_path

path('list_of_employees/<str:department>/', views.Pay_slip_list , name='emp_pay_list'),
```

or use `re_path`

```
re_path(r'^list_of_employees/(?P<department>[\w\-]+)/$', views.Pay_slip_list , name='emp_pay_list')
```

> use `path` instead of `url` for Django version >= 2.0, or use `re_path` for complex patterns, `re_path` is same as `url` method in lower versions

Comment: how ll i pass parameter from the html page syntax?    i added <str:department> this yet i am getting error.--- Reverse for 'emp_pay_list' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['hrmsapp/list_of_employees/<str:department>$']---

Comment: you are already passing it `href="{% url 'emp_pay_list' 'Information_technology' %}`. you can get this value in `department` variable in view

Comment: surround the arg value with single quote i.e `'Information_technology'` other places also

Comment: i am getting an error       Reverse for 'emp_pay' with arguments '('Information_technology',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['hrmsapp/employees_by_departments/<str:department>/$']
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/hrmsapp/Payslip_departments
Django Version: 2.0.7
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:

Comment: Updated my answer you are using django 2.0, use `path` to create urls.

Comment: sorry don't mind i am new to django can share an example ?

Comment: did you use the Url I have updated in the answer? any error logs

Comment: yes i used path as well as re-path i am getting the same error. yes i've changed the urls.py code and used single quotes.

Comment: Do you have GitHub repo of your code, I will look into it and point out the exact issue

Comment: thank you soo much now i am able to fetch the parameter properly. the mistake i had done was i had commented few part of code and it was giving the error.